# How can I make rvalue chaining of an Rc<RefCell<T>> work?

Tags: rust

I am trying to formalize my use of `Rc<RefCell<T>>`. This works fine:

```
use std::cell::{Ref, RefCell};
use std::rc::Rc;

struct SP<T> {
    object: Rc<RefCell<T>>,
}

impl<T> SP<T> {
    pub fn new(value: T) -> SP<T> {
        SP {
            object: Rc::new(RefCell::new(value)),
        }
    }
    pub fn get(&self) -> Ref<T> {
        self.object.borrow()
    }
}
// impl<T> Deref for SP<T> {
//     type Target = T;
//     fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
//         &self.object.borrow()
//     }
// }
struct Test {
    i: i32,
}
fn main() {
    let t = Test { i: 42 };
    let sp = SP::new(t);

    let tt = sp.get().i;

    println!("{}", tt)
}
```

I would like to sugar the use of `SP` so that I can do this:

```
fn main() {
    let t = Test { i: 42 };
    let sp = SP::new(t);

    let tt = sp.i; // implicit 'dereference'

    println!("{}", tt)
}
```

I tried to implement this in the commented out code. The problem is that the rvalue generated by `borrow()` refuses to live long enough to be consumed by the rest of the statement. Is there any magic spell I can cast over this code to persuade it to work?

Comment: TL;DR — you can't. That's kind of the point of runtime/dynamic borrow checking, as opposed to compile-time/static borrow checking. Presumably if you could do this, then `RefCell` would already allow you to do it and you wouldn't need the wrapper.

Comment: dont really see that including the word get() in a statement fundamentally changes the dynamic / static borrow mutability etc. Its just typing 6 less chars. I supposed I could call it g and get it down to 4 chars. Not asking to store the result or anything, just want the rvalue to last for the whole statement.